# How do I add margin to just background image?

Tags: css

I want to add a margin to the background image so that I distance it from the middle of the screen, but adding it inside that class adds a margin to the whole body.

```
body.poppage {
    background: url(/Imagenes/tip3.png) 50% 200px no-repeat #E2E4E9;
}
```

How could I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use the [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) property

Comment: but background position counts pixels necessarily from the left or right of the screen right? There is not way to start counting from the middle?

Comment: Create a container with this background, and center it on the page

Answer (score 16):

Use the containers padding to make a kind of margin for the background.

```
<div class="thebox">
    <p>HEY!</p>
</div>

div.thebox
{
box-sizing: border-box;
width:400px;
height:400px;

border: 2px solid #000000;
padding: 10px;

background: url(http://studio-creator.com/blog/public/html5.jpg) center;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-origin: content-box;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gann1pwm/

Comment: Very good example `background-origin` usage! Might be worth adding an explanation on why it's there (to make position relative to content, rather than to the padding edges as would be the default)

Comment: This is brilliant, I didn't know about "background-origin: content-box;". Thank you!

Comment: 2022, fantastic!

Answer (score 5):

this work with me i have 50px navbar

```
background-size: contain !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-position: 0 50px !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something else... like moving the image to the next child. You can make a wrapper div around your fixed-width div to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really add margins to a background image, since it's not actually an element. A couple things you might try:

1. If you've got a containing element just inside the body, you can apply the background image to this element and set margins on it.
2. If all you want is to make the background image appear to be floating within its container, set its background position.