# Vuetify and css to show svg image on the side on bigger screen

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, styling

I am trying to make my forms more attractive, by adding a picture on the right hand side if there are space.
I am working with vuetify, and typically want to do this when using  component.

I would prefer this to be easy to use.
Therefore I decided my images will always be displayed as 200px width.

I have two solutions, but I am sure there must be a better way to handle this!

Solution 1:

```
<v-card class="ma-2 pa-2">
  <v-icon> 2A     </v-icon>
  <v-card-title class="ma-2">
     side image SHOWING IMAGE in last v-col - hide on smaller than md
  </v-card-title>
  <v-card-text class="mr-5 ma-2 " >
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="11" sm="11" md="9" lg="8"
           class="right-side-line">
     <v-text-field label="This Label" append-icon="mdi-kettle" />
     <v-text-field label="Another Label" prepend-inner-icon="mdi-kettle" />
     <v-text-field label="Width" v-model="w" />
     <v-text-field label="Height" v-model="h" />
     vbp-mdAndUp{{ $vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp }}
     vbp-lgAndUp{{ $vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp }}
     <span class="ma-2">{{ this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name }} </span>
    </v-col>
   <v-col v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp" cols="1" md="3" lg="4"
          class="thebox">
   </v-col>
  </v-row>
  </v-card-text>
  <v-card-actions> <v-btn> Click Me </v-btn> <v-spacer/>  <v-btn> Or Click Me </v-btn> </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

Above is a bit nasty, and is such a lot of work to get something simple to work
(Will include styling below)

Solution 2

```
<v-card class="ma-2 pa-2" :class="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp ? 'thebox' : ''" elevation="-6" >
  <v-icon> 4B </v-icon>
  <v-card-title class="ma-2 "> rightside line and thebox in card (sol 4A) </v-card-title>
  <v-card-text class="right-side-line" :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp ? 'padding-right:290px' : ''">
    <v-text-field label="This Label" append-icon="mdi-kettle" />
    <v-text-field label="Another Label" prepend-inner-icon="mdi-kettle" />
    <v-text-field label="Width" v-model="w" />
    <v-text-field label="Height" v-model="h" />
    vbp-mdAndUp{{ $vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp }}
    vbp-lgAndUp{{ $vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp }}
    <span class="ma-2">{{ this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name }} </span>
  </v-card-text>
  <v-card-actions> <v-btn> Click Me </v-btn> <v-spacer/>  <v-btn> Or Click Me </v-btn> </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

Solution 2 has js code on v-card, and js code on v-card-text, this is to check size of screen. I believe I should be able to get this working with just a simple class name on my v-card

Something like  or  :-)

Styling used:

```
div.thebox
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694191/how-do-i-add-margin-to-just-background-image
  */
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-image: url('~@/img/GreenStripe.svg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-position: right;
}

.zaside {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex: 200px;
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url('~@/img/GreenStripe.svg');
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.right-side-line {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,black 33%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 3px 1px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

reading this before posting... I guess media query is the answer?
however - any help and feedback would be great!
From -  The CPT City Turtle

ps. I tried about 8 other options, that is why css "zaside" is included.

Comment: Got it working after reading up on css - Thanks Kevin Powell

Comment: ```div.thebox
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-image: url('~@/assets/Rect-Gray-Equality.svg');
  /* background-image: url('~@/assets/Rect-Gray-AttendanceHandInLug.svg'); */
  background-size: 120px auto;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-attachment: scroll, local;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-position: top right;
}
```